# Filebeat: How to remove log if some key or value exist?

Tags: logstash, filebeat

filebeat version 7.17.3

i have 3 different logs for example

```
{"level":"debug","message":"Start proxy checking","module":"proxy","timestamp":"2022-05-18 23:22:15 +0200"}
{"level":"info","message":"Attempt to get proxy","module":"proxy","timestamp":"2022-05-18 23:22:17 +0200"}
{"campaign":"18","level":"warn","message":"Missed or empty list","module":"loader","session":"pYpifim","timestamp":"2022-05-18 23:27:46 +0200"}
```

1. how is it possible to not provide/filter out the log to logstash or elasticsearch if level is equal "info"
2. how is it possible to not provide/filter out the log to logstash or elasticsearch if key campaign does not exist?

in FileBeat i have following

```
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
  - decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["message"]
      process_array: false
      max_depth: 1
      target: ""
      overwrite_keys: true
      add_error_key: true
  - drop_fields:
      fields: ["agent", "host", "log", "ecs", "input", "location"]
```

but with drop_fields i can remove some field and i need to not save completely log if key or value are exist!

in Logstash to delete those events is no problem - see below, but how to do this in filebeats?

```
/etc/logstash/conf.d/40-filebeat-to-logstash.conf                                              

input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    include_codec_tag => false
  }
}
filter {
  if "Start proxy checking" in [message] {
    drop { }
  }
  if "Attempt to get proxy" in [message] {
    drop { }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200"]
#    index => "myindex"
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

in filebeat there is drop events processor,

```
 processors:
  - drop_event:
      when:
        condition
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.17/drop-event.html